# How to repeat negative assertion in regexp

Tags: regex

```
array = ["/dima/www.xozmarket.by/abc/abc//abc"];
pattern = "%^/(dima|oleg)/([-a-z0-9]+)[.]+([-a-z0-9]+)[.]+(by|kz|ru)((?<!/)/abc)*%";
```

I want to test a string to find "//"

So as you can see here I use a negative assertion and as a result the testing string looks great for regexp, but not for me. But if I change this part of regexp `((?<!/)/abc)* to (?<!/)/abc(?<!/)/abc(?<!/)/abc(?<!/)/abc` - my test is ok! So how to avaoid manual repetition?

Comment: your regex works fine https://regex101.com/r/eR3cR0/1 . What's wrong with that?